# C++ increment/decrement operators behave differently when used in a single output statement

Tags: c++, console-application

So I have two C++ codes:

**The first one:**

```
int main()
{
    int a=10, b=8;

    b=a;
    ++a;
    b++;

    cout<<a<<"\n"<<b<<"\n"<<--b<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**The second one:**

```
int main()
{
    int a=10, b=8;

    b=a;
    ++a;
    b++;

    cout<<a<<"\n";
    cout<<b<<"\n";
    cout<<--b<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Their respective outputs are:

**The first output:**

```
11
10
10
```

**The second output:**

```
11
11
10
```

As you can notice, if I `cout` the values using a single line, the output is different than the output if I `cout` the values using multiple lines.

Can anybody please explain what's happening?

Thanks.

Comment: You have older version of compiler. this `cout<<a<<"\n"<<b<<"\n"<<--b<<"\n";` was UB until [c++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).. See the warning [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rAorWWOeZgZHdkXW) and [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PeFjJbrlKDWNclft)

Comment: What @JeJo said plus [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points).

Comment: Thank you so much @JeJo. I really appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score -2):

When you are executing in one line then

```
--b;
```

value is evaluated first and then printed in both **(b and --b)** .

and when you are executing cout in new line then :

```
--b;
```

value is evaluated at last.

Comment: The issue with evaluating the same value multiple times in one expression is described in the "possible duplicates" my friends above have already posted. Please do give them a read.